# A Static Link that References a Changing Link?

Tags: java, css

I'd like to make a link with a static, internal URL like "/directory/page" but then create ANOTHER link elsewhere that I change on a regular basis, that is referenced by that first, static link.

Thus I want to have one link that always changes and another link (that my users use) that stays the same...but references whatever my changing link is.

It's hard to even describe that. Ugh.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you, and see what you already tried.

Comment: This is achievable using redirects, but it's not clear to me: does static link redirect to dynamic link, or dynamic link redirects to static link?

Comment: Hi, I haven't 'tried' anything yet because I don't even know where to start on this.

Clarification for @M.Prokhorov static link redirects to dynamic link.

Comment: Then this means that static link point at some resource that knows the dynamic link, is notified whenever the dynamic link changes, and always responds with redirect to the dynamic link. Or have the same resource just fetching data from the dynamic url directly and relaying response. Exact implementation depends on what you have available in terms of resource implementations.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Well, the site is in Drupal, so PHP or JavaScript (jQuery) would be possibilities no?